# Keras multi instance classification problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

I'm trying to do a binary classification task on a dataset of 1D signals. Here are the input shapes of the training batch `x` and the groud truth batch `y`. In other words, I have 16 signals with 38400 time steps and 1 feature per time step for each batch. Each signal is classified into 150 time of one class (kind of multi instance learning problem).

> x shape (16, 38400, 1)
>
> y shape (16, 150, 1)

Here is the network I'm using so far:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=params['input_shape'], dropout=0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(params["num_categories"])))
model.add(Activation('softmax' if params['num_categories'] != 1 else 'sigmoid'))

from keras.optimizers import Adam
optimizer = Adam(lr=params['learning_rate'], clipnorm=params.get("clipnorm", 1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

return model
```

Please note that `params['input_shape']` is equal to `[:, :, None]`. Here are the output shapes of the network layers when running the code:

```
Tensor("lstm_1/transpose_1:0", shape=(?, ?, 2), dtype=float32) : (1, 38400, 2)
Tensor("time_distributed_1/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=float32) : (1, 38400, 1)
Tensor("activation_1/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=float32) : (1, 38400, 1)
```

The problem is that we're getting this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [4,150,1] vs. [4,38400,1]
     [[{{node metrics/acc/Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](_arg_activation_1_target_0_1/_65, metrics/acc/Round)]]
     [[{{node metrics/auroc/auc/assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_2/_93}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1152_...t/Switch_2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I know that this error is related to `y` that does not have the same shape of the output of the network. But, I'm not sure what kind of layer should I add to the network in order to get the required shape. Can you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a fully-connected layer to your network. If the output of your network is size B, and you want it to be size A, you can define a fully connected layer to take input of size B and produce output of size A. Please see the documentation of tf.keras.layers.Dense: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense